# Why these types are incompatible?

Tags: typescript, antd, apollo-client, graphql-codegen

I have a Value type like this:

```js
export type Value = {
   __typename?: 'Value',
  key?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>,
  label?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>,
  value?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>,
};
```

And a query result type (generated apollo hooks) like this:

```js
Maybe<Maybe<{
    __typename?: "Value" | undefined;
} & Pick<Value, "key" | "label" | "value">>[]>
```

I'm trying to pass this query result to a function:

```js
const getValues = (contacts: Value[]) => {
  const values = contacts.map(e => e["value"]);
  return values;
};
```

For some reason, TypeScript says that those types are incompatible. My function call:

```js
getValues( dataFilters!.caseListFilters!.contacts )
```

TypeScript error:

```
Argument of type 'Maybe<Maybe<{ __typename?: "Value" | undefined; } & Pick<Value, "key" | "label" | "value">>[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Value[]'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Value[]'.ts(2345)
```

Can someone help me to understand what is wrong with these types?
I know that `as Value[]` solves the problem but I have no idea why.

```js
getValues( dataFilters!.caseListFilters!.contacts as Value[] //no error )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Maybe types, which are nullables at a higher order. So although you assert that they are not `undefined` using `!`, you are asserting that they are in fact `Maybe` the thing. A thing of `Maybe` type, when it *is* there, is still only *maybe* the value.

For a maybe you have to unwrap the value safely to get a guaranteed value.

Where is the `Maybe` type from? Sanctuary.js? fp-ts? Go to Definition and understand what Maybe type you are using, then read the docs. You need to get the value out of it.

Comment: Thank you, but I understand only the first part of your answer. What it means to "unwrap the value safely"? I came across [true-myth](https://true-myth.js.org/modules/_maybe_.html) where they talk about unwrapping Just and Nothing, but all I've found regarding my Maybe implementation is this: `export type Maybe<T> = T | null;`